# Time tracking across devices with tagging

Tags: macos, ios, software-recommendation, icloud, time-tracking

I'm looking for a quality time-tracking app/system.  Here are the features I need:

- Works on both OS X and iOS with syncing (iCloud or Dropbox preferred)
- Includes tag/label system to allow for filtered analysis

Most of the apps I've tried don't meet one or both of these criteria.  I have no use for billing features, so those are of no concern to me.

My environment is such that I work on many similar projects across multiple buildings.  I also attend meetings with people from different buildings and departments, often in multiple configurations.  I want to be able to drill down and see how much time I am devoting to each project, each building, each department, each staff member, and so on.  The only way I can think this might work is with tags.  Projects alone don't allow this.